# How to find resource in layout in Android studio

Tags: android, layout, resources

I have a question on Android studio
In layout how can I find resource by resource name?
Project has many layout pages
Is there any way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press Double Shift and there you can write class/resource name and it will show you options below you can click on that